# How to configure mqtt.js to connect to iot.eclipse.org over websockets

Tags: node.js, browser, websocket, browserify, mqtt

Edit: My issue is now this.  I can connect to *iot.eclipse.org* using http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client, using port 80.  When I connect via a [browsified mqtt.js client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browserify) I am getting the following error :

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://iot.eclipse.org/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

I've tried ports 8080, 8000, 1883 and 80, without any luck.  Any suggestions?

------------ Original question below -----------

I want to connect with a mqtt broker using mqtt over websockets.  My client will need to run in a browser.

TO achieve this I am using [mqtt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) library and am following [these instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browserify).

Everything works when running against the public broker at *broker.mqttdashboard.com*.  However when I connect to the public brokers at *iot.eclipse.org* and *test.mosquitto.org* I get HTTP errors.

I think the problem is incorrect configuration of the client when running against the second two brokers, but I'm struggling to find any help.

Heres the configuration, is there anyone out there who can help me?

```
  // Works fine
  var options = {
    host: "broker.mqttdashboard.com",
    port: 8000
  };

  // Doesn't work
  /*var options = {
    host: "m2m.eclipse.org",
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    protocolVersion: 3
  };*/

  // Doesn't work
  /*var options = {
    host: "test.mosquitto.org",
    protocolId: 'mosqOtti',
    protocolVersion: 3
  };*/

  var client = mqtt.connect(options);
```

Let me know if theres any more information you need!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Both test.mosquitto.org and iot.eclipse.org are both websockets enabled (for a long time now actually).

You already have got test.mosquitto.org working - the key there is using port 8080.

The current iot.eclipse.org configuration expects the connection url to be `ws://iot.eclipse.org/mqtt`.

Comment: Still getting a 404 when using iot.eclipse.org/mqtt as the host, despite trying a whole load of different ports...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *m2m.eclipse.org* / *iot.eclipse.org* or *test.mosquitto.org* have websockets enabled.

*broker.mqttdashboard.com* runs a HiveMQ underneath which has native websockets enabled.

So in short, I don't think this is a configuration problem on your side. To make sure, you can check this web application and see if the other brokers work with that: http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer!  I'll have a look at the web socket client you posted.  However, test.mosquito.org does have web sockets enabled, according to http://test.mosquitto.org/ws.html.  Not so sure about it.eclipse.org though...

Comment: Just  successfully connected to the test.mosquitto.org broker with the following parameters using mqtt.js: 
        var options = {
           host: "test.mosquitto.org",
           port: 8080 }

Comment: iot.eclipse.org works with port 80 in the hivemq client, but I'm struggling to get it working in mqtt.js.